# How to solve the problem of infinite height in swiper (direction: "vertical")

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a vertical slider swiper on my web page.
I want each slide to be the height of its own textual content.
If I do not set a certain height (for example 500 pixels), with the height provided by the swiper (100%), an infinite height will be created.
I just want each slide to be as tall as the text when the user clicks on each of the swiper-paginations.
And I do not want to be able to move slides with the mouse or touch.
Version used: Swiper 7.0.1.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    direction: "vertical",
    speed: 600,
    allowTouchMove: false,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
    },
});
```

```css
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /* height: 500px; */
    /* min-height: 500px; */
    max-height: 500px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="hmp--slide">
     <div class="swiper mySwiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                         </p>                                    
                         <h4>hmp</h4>
                    </div>
               </div>
                
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                          </p>                                    
                          <h4>hmp</h4>
                     </div>
               </div>
                
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                         </p>                                    
                         <h4>hmp</h4>
                    </div>
               </div>
                
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                         </p>                                    
                         <h4>hmp</h4>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try the autoHeight property? https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-autoHeight

Answer (score 3):

Like Thomas mentioned in the comments you could use `autoHeight: true`. But this will only fix the infinite height issue. It will not set the slide height to the content height of that slide.

**Working example:** (*with fix height to fit in the stacksnippet*)

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    direction: "vertical",
    speed: 600,
    allowTouchMove: false,
    autoHeight: true,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
    },
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="hmp--slide">
     <div class="swiper mySwiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                         </p>                                    
                         <h4>hmp</h4>
                    </div>
               </div>
                
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                          </p>                                    
                          <h4>hmp</h4>
                     </div>
               </div>
                
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                         </p>                                    
                         <h4>hmp</h4>
                    </div>
               </div>
                
               <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="slide--body">
                         <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates sapiente ipsa, ducimus, doloremque ipsam molestiae quasi beatae autem debitis fugiat corrupti ad incidunt suscipit odio cupiditate modi porro sequi. Voluptate.
                         </p>                                    
                         <h4>hmp</h4>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello my friend. thank a lot. autoHeight: true => solve infinite height issue but When the text content of one of the slides is long, the height will be less than the text content. It is better not to have a certain height And determine the height according to the text content.

Comment: It's for demonstration to fit in the stack snippet...

Comment: thank a lot my friend, but If we only set the autoHeight: true, And if we do not set a certain amount of height, (everything remains by default swiper), again the height of each .swiper-slide is unacceptably high.

Comment: Thank you, `autoHeight: true` solved the issue.